# ListView crashes at the end of the list

Tags: android-studio

I'm just a beginner in programming and I need a list view of cars. For the most part it works but then when I scroll at the bottom of the list, it crashes.

---

This is the code for the Java class:

```
package com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CarbonEmissions extends AppCompatActivity {
    int [] IMAGES = {R.drawable.chevycruze, R.drawable.fordeverest, R.drawable.fordfiesta, R.drawable.hondacitysedan, R.drawable.hondajazz, R.drawable.hyundaiaccent, R.drawable.isuzudmax, R.drawable.kiapicanto,
            R.drawable.mitsumirage, R.drawable.mitsusuvmontero, R.drawable.nissancerifo, R.drawable.subaruxv, R.drawable.suzukivitara, R.drawable.toyotafortuner,
            R.drawable.toyotainnova5, R.drawable.toyotainnova6, R.drawable.toyotarevo};
    String [] MAKE = {"Chevrolet", "Ford", "Ford", "Honda", "Honda", "Hyundai", "Isuzu", "Kia", "Mitsubishi", "Mitsubishi", "Nissan", "Subaru", "Suzuki", "Toyota",
            "Totoya","Totoya", "Totoya", "Totoya"};
    String [] MODEL = {"Cruze", "Everest", "Fiesta", "City", "Jazz", "Accent", "D Max", "Picanto", "Mirage", "Montero", "Cefiro", "XV", "Vitara", "Fortuner", "Innova", "Innova", "Revo"};
    String [] YEAR  = {"2012", "2016", "2013", "2018", "2009", "2010", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2010", "1997", "2015", "2012", "2015", "2016", "2004"};
    String [] FUEL = {"Gasoline", "Diesel", "Unleaded", "Gasoline", "Gasoline", "Diesel", "Diesel", "Diesel", "Gas / Unleaded", "Diesel", "Gasoline", "Gasoline", "Gasoline", "Diesel", "Diesel", "Gasoline"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carbon_emissions);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView_make=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView5_make);
            TextView textView_model=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView6_model);
            TextView textView_year=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView7_year);
            TextView textView_fuel=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView8_fuel);

            imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[i]);
            textView_make.setText(MAKE[i]);
            textView_model.setText(MODEL[i]);
            textView_year.setText(YEAR[i]);
            textView_fuel.setText(FUEL[i]);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling.CarbonEmissions"
    android:background="@drawable/green">
 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/ListView"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CUSTOM XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize = "22sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5_make"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize = "22sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6_model"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5_make"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize = "22sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView7_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5_make"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5_make"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize = "22sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView8_fuel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6_model"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6_model"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7_year"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ERROR LOG

```
02-06 18:52:03.054 19152-19152/? E/Zygote: v2
02-06 18:52:03.055 19152-19152/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10257
02-06 18:52:03.055 19152-19152/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-06 18:52:03.057 19152-19152/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-06 18:52:03.058 19152-19152/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
02-06 18:52:03.060 19152-19152/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling 
02-06 18:52:03.065 19152-19152/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-06 18:52:03.093 19152-19152/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-06 18:52:03.094 19152-19152/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-06 18:52:03.110 19152-19159/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-06 18:52:03.110 19152-19159/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
02-06 18:52:03.303 19152-19152/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling-1/lib/arm64
02-06 18:52:03.319 19152-19152/? D/ContextRelationMgrBrdg: loadKlass() : caller=com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.<clinit>:28 android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication:840 
02-06 18:52:03.329 19152-19152/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-06 18:52:03.407 19152-19152/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-06 18:52:03.499 19152-19152/? D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:03.500 19152-19152/? D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:03.776 19152-19152/? D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=73
02-06 18:52:03.776 19152-19152/? D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: setView = DecorView@2b0419d[WelcomeScreen] touchMode=true
02-06 18:52:03.820 19152-19170/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-06 18:52:03.820 19152-19170/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-06 18:52:03.829 19152-19170/? D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling
02-06 18:52:03.833 19152-19170/? D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
02-06 18:52:03.854 19152-19152/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-06 18:52:03.860 19152-19152/? D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
02-06 18:52:03.860 19152-19152/? D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
02-06 18:52:03.860 19152-19152/? V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@577f612 nm : com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling ic=null
02-06 18:52:03.860 19152-19152/? I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
02-06 18:52:03.867 19152-19165/? D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
02-06 18:52:04.255 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4f971e3 nm : com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling ic=null
02-06 18:52:05.378 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-06 18:52:05.380 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
02-06 18:52:05.383 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
02-06 18:52:05.383 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
02-06 18:52:05.486 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-06 18:52:05.517 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@8b1a874[WelcomeScreen]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
02-06 18:52:05.600 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.601 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.831 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.843 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.851 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.858 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.863 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:05.887 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=84
02-06 18:52:05.887 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: setView = DecorView@8c135d0[MainMenu] touchMode=true
02-06 18:52:05.947 19152-19170/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
02-06 18:52:06.249 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
02-06 18:52:06.249 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
02-06 18:52:06.251 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7cbdefc nm : com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling ic=null
02-06 18:52:06.251 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
02-06 18:52:06.268 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=89
02-06 18:52:06.268 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=80
02-06 18:52:07.151 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-06 18:52:07.246 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-06 18:52:07.292 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@67d193[MainMenu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
02-06 18:52:07.367 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.368 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.378 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-06 18:52:07.383 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@f76e218
02-06 18:52:07.385 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@511c471
02-06 18:52:07.385 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@511c471
02-06 18:52:07.403 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
02-06 18:52:07.404 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@2d14256[CarbonEmissions]: setView = DecorView@9d3a2d7[CarbonEmissions] touchMode=true
02-06 18:52:07.443 19152-19170/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
02-06 18:52:07.454 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.459 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.462 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.465 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.499 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.501 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.503 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.505 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.538 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.539 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.541 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.543 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.574 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.580 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.582 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.586 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.628 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.631 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.634 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.636 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.668 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.670 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.671 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.673 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:07.700 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/AbsListView:  onsize change 
02-06 18:52:07.818 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@2d14256[CarbonEmissions]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
02-06 18:52:07.818 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@2d14256[CarbonEmissions]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
02-06 18:52:07.822 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@acf8f8d nm : com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling ic=null
02-06 18:52:07.822 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
02-06 18:52:07.836 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=91
02-06 18:52:07.836 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=89
02-06 18:52:09.229 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@2d14256[CarbonEmissions]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-06 18:52:09.331 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.339 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.347 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.355 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.415 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.422 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.426 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.430 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.470 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.474 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.478 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.481 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.519 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.522 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.525 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.528 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.561 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/ViewRootImpl@2d14256[CarbonEmissions]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-06 18:52:09.634 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.638 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.643 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.648 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.701 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.705 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.709 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.713 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.759 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.761 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.763 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.764 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.791 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.792 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.793 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.795 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.840 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.841 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.842 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.843 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.893 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.895 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.899 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.902 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.977 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.980 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.983 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:09.986 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
02-06 18:52:10.010 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-06 18:52:10.011 19152-19152/com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling, PID: 19152
                                                                                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=16
                                                                                               at com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling.CarbonEmissions$CustomAdapter.getView(CarbonEmissions.java:61)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3229)
                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2147)
                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:767)
                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:731)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:8378)
                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:2065)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:7805)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:635)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **array Index out of bound exception** that says that you are trying to access element 16 that is the 17th element in the array which contains only the 16 elements.

So, you can modify the getcount() like this

`public int getCount() {
      return Year.length;
    }`

or can do as shown by the @Neil

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
```

you should probably check if the view == null before you use it.  Potentially, there isn't a view to show (as you are beyond the end of the list view).

```
if(view==null)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Sorry I am just a beginner

Comment: Add the lines from the 2nd panel in my answer to the line underneath the code from the 1st panel.